# Кэширование результатов функции

Tags: кэширование, java

Есть функция с целым аргументом, возвращающая некий объект

```
Object get(int n)
```

Функция работает долго и хочется не вызывать её повторно для одинаковых значений, а использовать что-то вроде кэширующего прокси, чтобы редкоиспользуемые значения из кэша удалялись при недостатке памяти.
Есть ли готовые стандартные решения?

Comment: по-моему, вы уже не первый раз ставите метку android не к чему. Этот вопрос относится к Java.

Comment: я ставлю на всякий случай, потому что не всё что есть в java есть в android

Comment: Может в [этой статье][1] найдете что то нужное


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/140338/

Comment: Может кто ещё что посоветует?

Comment: @michael ну то ж вообще про javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача достаточно популярна, поэтому есть много готовых решений. Ключевое слово для поиска - LRU. Вот один с примеров использования [Java LRU cache](http://www.javaspecialist.ru/2012/02/java-lru-cache.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Вот ещё нашёл что-то с ипользованием SoftReference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646257/lru-linkedhashmap-that-limits-size-based-on-available-memory